# How to add a script as an icon in topbar

Tags: 16.04, gnome

I would really like to have my .sh script for disabling/enabling touchscreen on my computer as a button in the gnome top bar(indicator bar).
I recently switched DE from unity to plain gnome.

I was able to find how you could add it as a launcher icon or desktop icon, but I would really love to have it in the topbar.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to create an indicator app.

A quick example that you can work with is:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

# This code is an example for a tutorial on Ubuntu Unity/Gnome AppIndicators:
# http://candidtim.github.io/appindicator/2014/09/13/ubuntu-appindicator-step-by-step.html
# https://gist.github.com/candidtim/7290a1ad6e465d680b68

import os
import signal
import json
import subprocess

from urllib2 import Request, urlopen # URLError

from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator
from gi.repository import Notify as notify



APPINDICATOR_ID = 'myappindicator'

def main():
    indicator = appindicator.Indicator.new(APPINDICATOR_ID, os.path.abspath('sample_icon.svg'), appindicator.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)
    indicator.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
    indicator.set_menu(build_menu())
    notify.init(APPINDICATOR_ID)
    gtk.main()

def build_menu():
    menu = gtk.Menu()

    item_myapp = gtk.MenuItem('MyApp')
    item_myapp.connect('activate', myapp)
    menu.append(item_myapp)

    item_quit1 = gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
    item_quit1.connect('activate', quit1)
    menu.append(item_quit1)

    menu.show_all()
    return menu

def fetch_joke():
    request = Request('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random?limitTo=[nerdy]')
    response = urlopen(request)
    joke = json.loads(response.read())['value']['joke']
    return joke

def myapp(_):
    subprocess.call("myapp.sh", shell=True)
    return myapp

def quit1(_):
    notify.uninit()
    gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    main()
```

In the example above just change the `myapp.sh` to a full pathname of your script and it will run.  When you run the script it will place the item in the indicator to the menubar.

Details can be found at:
http://candidtim.github.io/appindicator/2014/09/13/ubuntu-appindicator-step-by-step.html

and
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators